# Optimize MySql Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql

```
  SELECT 
  u.`username` 'Name',
  (SELECT 
    IFNULL(ROUND(COUNT(1) / COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y')))),0)
  FROM
    `leadfollwup_det` AS lf1
  WHERE lf1.`DialedUserID` = u.userID 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') >=  DATE_FORMAT(@FrDate,'%d-%b-%Y')
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') <=  DATE_FORMAT(@ToDate,'%d-%b-%Y') 
    AND  DATE_FORMAT( lf1.`DialedTime`, '%H') < 8) 'LessThan8AM',
  (SELECT 
    IFNULL(ROUND(COUNT(1) / COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y')))),0)
  FROM
    `leadfollwup_det` AS lf1
  WHERE lf1.`DialedUserID` = u.userID 
   AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') >=  DATE_FORMAT(@FrDate,'%d-%b-%Y')
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') <=  DATE_FORMAT(@ToDate,'%d-%b-%Y') 
    AND  DATE_FORMAT( lf1.`DialedTime`, '%H') = 8 ) 'From_8_To_9',
  (SELECT 
    IFNULL(ROUND(COUNT(1) / COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y')))),0)
  FROM
    `leadfollwup_det` AS lf1 
  WHERE lf1.`DialedUserID` = u.userID 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') >=  DATE_FORMAT(@FrDate,'%d-%b-%Y')
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') <=  DATE_FORMAT(@ToDate,'%d-%b-%Y') 
    AND  DATE_FORMAT( lf1.`DialedTime`, '%H') = 9 ) 'From_9_To_10',
  (SELECT 
    IFNULL(ROUND(COUNT(1) / COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y')))),0)
  FROM
    `leadfollwup_det` AS lf1 
  WHERE lf1.`DialedUserID` = u.userID 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') >=  DATE_FORMAT(@FrDate,'%d-%b-%Y')
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') <=  DATE_FORMAT(@ToDate,'%d-%b-%Y') 
    AND  DATE_FORMAT( lf1.`DialedTime`, '%H') = 10 ) 'From_10_To_11',
  (SELECT 
    IFNULL(ROUND(COUNT(1) / COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y')))),0)
  FROM
    `leadfollwup_det` AS lf1 
  WHERE lf1.`DialedUserID` = u.userID 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') >=  DATE_FORMAT(@FrDate,'%d-%b-%Y')
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') <=  DATE_FORMAT(@ToDate,'%d-%b-%Y') 
    AND  DATE_FORMAT( lf1.`DialedTime`, '%H') = 11 ) 'From_11_To_12',
  (SELECT 
    IFNULL(ROUND(COUNT(1) / COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y')))),0)
  FROM
    `leadfollwup_det` AS lf1 
  WHERE lf1.`DialedUserID` = u.userID 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') >=  DATE_FORMAT(@FrDate,'%d-%b-%Y')
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') <=  DATE_FORMAT(@ToDate,'%d-%b-%Y') 
    AND  DATE_FORMAT( lf1.`DialedTime`, '%H') = 12 ) 'From_12_To_1',
  (SELECT 
    IFNULL(ROUND(COUNT(1) / COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y')))),0)
  FROM
    `leadfollwup_det` AS lf1 
  WHERE lf1.`DialedUserID` = u.userID 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') >=  DATE_FORMAT(@FrDate,'%d-%b-%Y')
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') <=  DATE_FORMAT(@ToDate,'%d-%b-%Y') 
    AND  DATE_FORMAT( lf1.`DialedTime`, '%H') = 13 ) 'From_1_To_2',
  (SELECT 
    IFNULL(ROUND(COUNT(1) / COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y')))),0)
  FROM
    `leadfollwup_det` AS lf1 
  WHERE lf1.`DialedUserID` = u.userID 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') >=  DATE_FORMAT(@FrDate,'%d-%b-%Y')
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') <=  DATE_FORMAT(@ToDate,'%d-%b-%Y') 
    AND  DATE_FORMAT( lf1.`DialedTime`, '%H') = 14 ) 'From_2_To_3',
  (SELECT 
    IFNULL(ROUND(COUNT(1) / COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y')))),0)
  FROM
    `leadfollwup_det` AS lf1 
  WHERE lf1.`DialedUserID` = u.userID 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') >=  DATE_FORMAT(@FrDate,'%d-%b-%Y')
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') <=  DATE_FORMAT(@ToDate,'%d-%b-%Y') 
    AND  DATE_FORMAT( lf1.`DialedTime`, '%H') = 15 ) 'From_3_To_4',
  (SELECT 
    IFNULL(ROUND(COUNT(1) / COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y')))),0)
  FROM
    `leadfollwup_det` AS lf1 
  WHERE lf1.`DialedUserID` = u.userID 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') >=  DATE_FORMAT(@FrDate,'%d-%b-%Y')
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') <=  DATE_FORMAT(@ToDate,'%d-%b-%Y') 
    AND  DATE_FORMAT( lf1.`DialedTime`, '%H') = 16 ) 'From_4_To_5',
  (SELECT 
    IFNULL(ROUND(COUNT(1) / COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y')))),0)
  FROM
    `leadfollwup_det` AS lf1 
  WHERE lf1.`DialedUserID` = u.userID 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') >=  DATE_FORMAT(@FrDate,'%d-%b-%Y')
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') <=  DATE_FORMAT(@ToDate,'%d-%b-%Y') 
    AND  DATE_FORMAT( lf1.`DialedTime`, '%H') = 17 ) 'From_5_To_6',
  (SELECT 
    IFNULL(ROUND(COUNT(1) / COUNT(DISTINCT(DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y')))),0)
  FROM
    `leadfollwup_det` AS lf1 
  WHERE lf1.`DialedUserID` = u.userID 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') >=  DATE_FORMAT(@FrDate,'%d-%b-%Y')
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf1.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') <=  DATE_FORMAT(@ToDate,'%d-%b-%Y') 
    AND  DATE_FORMAT( lf1.`DialedTime`, '%H') > 17 ) 'GreaterThan6PM'
FROM
  `user_m` AS u 
  INNER JOIN `leadfollwup_det` AS lf 
    ON u.`userid` = lf.`DialedUserID` 
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') >=  DATE_FORMAT(@FrDate,'%d-%b-%Y')
    AND DATE_FORMAT(lf.`DialedTime`,'%d-%b-%Y') <=  DATE_FORMAT(@ToDate,'%d-%b-%Y') 
    # AND  (DATE_FORMAT( lf.`DialedTime`, '%H')  between 0 and 24 ) 
GROUP BY u.`userid` ;
```

Comment: *sigh*. There's no question, you havent formatted the code properly, you havent even asked nicely for what you want and this isn't a request site. Try something

Comment: Isn't a comparison between unformatted dates largely the same as a comparison between formatted dates?

Comment: This query takes long time to finish (approx 20 minute)

Comment: please help to rewrite this for better performance,thanks in advance